# How to build a regular expression which prohibits hyphens from appearing at the start and end of a string?

Tags: regex

I want to build a regular expression which only matches `[A-Za-z0-9\-]` with an additional rule that hyphens (`-`) are not allowed to appear at the start and at the end.

For example:

`my-site` is matched.

`m` is matched.

`mysite-` is not matched.

`-mysite` is not matched.

Currently, I've come up with `^[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+$`.

But this doesn't match `m`.

How can I change my regular expression so that it fits my needs?

Comment: It is so common. `^[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)?$` or `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds:

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]*(?<!-)$
```

The reason this works is that look arounds don't consume input, so the look ahead and the look behind can both assert on the *same* character.

Note that you don't need to escape the dash within the character class if it's the first or last character.

Comment: If the regex is used in .NET or Python 3, `\w` matches more than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` by default.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew already corrected